# Adding AutoMapper via Asp.Net Core Dependency injection and inject into profiles

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using ASP.net Core with AutoMapper. To get the DI running, I use the AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection Nuget-Package and let AutoMapper register the profiles via

```
    private static void InitializeAutoMapper(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper();
    }
```

This works fine, but for some Profiles, I'd like to inject also some dependencies to them, for example:

```
public class IndividualDtoProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly IIndividualFactory _individualFactory;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public IndividualDtoProfile(IIndividualFactory individualFactory, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _individualFactory = individualFactory;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IndividualDtoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Individual, IndividualDto>();

        CreateMap<IndividualDto, Individual>()
            .ConstructUsing(
                dto =>
                {
                    var gender = _mapper.Map<IndividualGender>(dto.Gender);
                    return _individualFactory.CreateIndividual(dto.FirstName, dto.LastName, gender, dto.BirthDate);
                });
    }
}
```

The only relevant discussion I found is here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automapper-users/5XK7pqGu_Tg

Which pretty much seems to suggest to not use the goodness of the existing possibilities, but manually map the Profiles. The only other possibility I'd see is to provide a static ServiceProvider-Singleton, which also doesn't seem too appealing.

Is there already a possibility, to use ASP.Net Core with AutoMapper and let dependencies inject into Profiles?

Edit: Due to the comment, probably I'm also something fundamentally wrong: I'm learning Domain Driven Design, where I have an application layer. I'd like to map the DTOs, which are used from a Web-Service, back to the domain entities, and I assumed, it would make sense to use the Factories there too, since otherwise I would bypass the logic in the Factories.

Comment: Does it really make sense to add DI here? Finally, it's just mapping of one object to another. If you have tests, you would need to test/mock mapping too. Double work from my point of view.

Comment: hm? I don't understand your point: I'd like to generically map with AutoMapper, but for some maps I'd like to use Factories in order to assure some invariants and assuring, that every object is created for its specific Factory.

Comment: Why the hell would you want to use/inject `IMapper` inside a profile??! The profiles are used to add registrations, before the mapper is ready to be used (i.e. to perform a validation via `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`). While I generally prefer to inject IMapper anywhere too, there are some limitations though. Are you using Automapper's EF projections? They don't work easily with injections, since the `.ProjectTo()` method uses the static `Mapper` class instead

Comment: Also I assume your `Individual` is an EF/EF Core Poco, in which case: **never map from Dto to Persistence or Domain Models**, it will bite you really hard (EF Core works with references, mapping this way may break the way how EF Core handles the entities, especially on collections)

Comment: @MatthiasMüller I prefer to use Mapping after all magic stuff (validations, getting data from DB etc). It should be as simple as possible. (IMO)

Comment: I added a comment, why I tried to introcude it that way in the first place, probably I got something fundamentally wrong there. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported out of the box, by design. If you want it, you have to do it yourself using your DI container. This has been discussed many times before. For example, [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2208). The [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dependency-injection).

Comment: Thanks, searching for another solutuon then.